# image not rendering in flatlist -react native

Tags: react-native, image

I am rendering data from a separate file and and passing it through props to my image icon but I am unable to render the image.

```
import Icon from "../components/Icon";
import Data from "../API/data";

const Index = () => {
  
  return (
    <View style={style.display}>
      <FlatList
        data={Data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <BusyIcon
              text={item.name}
              imageSource={`require("${item.image}")`}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The component code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";

// import { Audio } from "expo-av";

const Icon = ({ imageSource, text }) => {
  console.log(imageSource);
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={imageSource} style={style.image} />
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
  },
});

export default Icon;
```

Everything looks right but why are the images not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

The images are not rendering because:

You have imported the Icon component as 'Icon' on line #1 but you are using the Icon component as 'BusyIcon' inside the flatList which is wrong. So replace Busy Icon with Icon.

Also for demo purposes, Check this: https://snack.expo.dev/@haseebahmed/abab6f